# Launching app when the calendar event comes

Tags: android, calendar

I'm writing an app that would make a calendar event and then, when this event comes, it would open and send notification to user. First part I've already done. But with the second I have some problems.

So my question: "Is it possible to open app when the calendar event comes? And if yes, how can i do it?"

Comment: I would ask if this really would be the best approach.  The notification would be enough for me as a user.  Anything else could just annoy me.

Comment: @JaySnayder Through the app notification user will be able to for ex "call the contact" or "send a sms". (User will see only my app's notification)